# Froala Editor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor, froala

I use froala editor first time and now I have problems. On the first page froala works very good, but on the second page - editor doesn't work. When I click on toolbar buttons I have noting. Text length always equals zero and placeholder doesn't hide. Please Help me to fix this problem.

```
<script src="/public/bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

And.

```
$("#page_x2j1").froalaEditor();
```

Comment: You have typo (missing ") in your second code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this reference to do the initialization on load and everything worked great.

```
$.getScript("js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js", function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a conflict with something else on the page. It would worth checking if there aren't other JS libraries which are preventing the editor editor toolbar to work correctly.